# Remove extra commas in a field from csv file affecting other rows with good data

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which should remove extra commas in a field, (field 13), and it is working fine.

However, if I have other rows that have no data in this field, some of the good rows become affected.

In my input, only row 2, *(do not count the header)*, has an issue

```
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN ,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Supplies
```

However, when I run the script, row `3`, `7`, `11` got affected, *(these are good rows)*.

(Showing only 3 row as an example, an extra comma was added to the row causing data shifted over when displayed in xls)

```
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105
```

Input:

```
StoreNumber,PurchaseOrderNumber,Last4DIG,ParticipantName,PurchaseOrderDate,POLineNumber,UnitPrice,Quantity,UnitOfMeasure,PartDescription,StartDate,EndDate,LineDetail,ParticipantID,BuyerContacts,FacilityCode,DetailsFreeText
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Books         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN ,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Supplies         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Mandatory Taxes         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Textbooks, ebooks and manuals,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Books        
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,$50 worth of school supplies,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Supplies         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,No more than 10%,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Detailed,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Mandatory Taxes         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Books         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,$50 PER TERM MAX UNLESS APPROVED BY VRC,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Supplies         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Mandatory Taxes
```

Output:

```
StoreNumber,PurchaseOrderNumber,Last4DIG,ParticipantName,PurchaseOrderDate,POLineNumber,UnitPrice,Quantity,UnitOfMeasure,PartDescription,StartDate,EndDate,LineDetail,ParticipantID,BuyerContacts,FacilityCode,DetailsFreeText
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Books         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN ,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Supplies         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Mandatory Taxes         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Textbooks  ebooks and manuals,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Books         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,$50 worth of school supplies,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Supplies         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,,No more than 10%,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Detailed,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Mandatory Taxes         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Books         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,$50 PER TERM MAX UNLESS APPROVED BY VRC,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Supplies         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Mandatory Taxes
```

Code:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all files with .csv extension in current folder
for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    ECHO/
    ECHO Input: "%%F"
    TYPE "%%F"

    rem Each file have comma-separated columns: may be 17 columns or more
    rem Keep columns 1-12 the same. After that, generate 5 columns more:
    rem the last 4 columns are the same
    rem the 5th before last column contain the rest of columns separated by space

    (for /F "usebackq tokens=1-12* delims=," %%a in ("%%F") do (
            set "restAfter12=%%m"
            set "last="
            set "lastBut1="
            set "lastBut2="
            set "lastBut3="
            set "lastBut4="

            for %%A in ("!restAfter12:,=" "!") do (    
                set "lastBut4=!lastBut4! !lastBut3!"
                set "lastBut3=!lastBut2!"         
                set "lastBut2=!lastBut1!"
                set "lastBut1=!last!"
                set "last=%%~A"
            )
            echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,!lastBut4:~5!,!lastBut3!,!lastBut2!,!lastBut1!,!last!
        )) > "%%~NF.out"
    ECHO Output: "%%~NF.out"
    TYPE "%%~NF.out"
)
```

I would appreciate if someone could point out what was missing in my code to cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your data contain asterisks `*` that are expanded as filenames in `FOR` command, so the line must be split in fields with no use of `FOR`.

It is easier to fix this issue in the [simpler code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518119/778560) I provided to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem General method to keep the first N columns the same
rem and group additional fields in column N+1

rem Define the number of "same" and "total" columns:
set /A "same=12, last=17"

rem Process all files with .csv extension in current folder
for %%F in (*.csv) do (

ECHO/
ECHO Input: "%%F"
TYPE "%%F"

   rem Process all lines of current file
   (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%F") do (

      set "line=%%a"
      set "head="
      set "tail="

      rem Split current line in comma-separated fields
      call :splitLine

      rem Process the fields
      for /L %%i in (1,1,!n!) do (
         if %%i leq %same% (         rem Accumulate field in "head" columns
            set "head=!head!!f[%%i]!,"
         ) else if %%i leq %last% (  rem Accumulate field in "tail" columns
            set "tail=!tail!!f[%%i]!,"
         ) else (  rem Combine one field from beginning of "tail" and accumulate last field
            for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%x in ("!tail!") do set "tail=%%x %%y!f[%%i]!,"
         )
      )

      echo !head!!tail:~0,-1!

   )) > "%%~NF.out"

ECHO Output: "%%~NF.out"
TYPE "%%~NF.out"

)
goto :EOF


:splitLine

set "n=1"
set "f[%n%]=%line:,=" & set /A "n+=1" & set "f[!n!]=%"
exit /B
```

Output:

```
StoreNumber,PurchaseOrderNumber,Last4DIG,ParticipantName,PurchaseOrderDate,POLineNumber,UnitPrice,Quantity,UnitOfMeasure,PartDescription,StartDate,EndDate,LineDetail,ParticipantID,BuyerContacts,FacilityCode,DetailsFreeText
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Books         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN ,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Required Supplies         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8455,343248202,6528,IVAN,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/31/2022,,37449257,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31917105,Mandatory Taxes         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Textbooks  ebooks and manuals,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Books        
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,$50 worth of school supplies,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Required Supplies         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,No more than 10%,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8094,459244329,7152,ALFRED,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,12/18/2022,Detailed,32818318,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,31016230,Mandatory Taxes         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,1,0,1,EA,Required Books,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Books         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,2,0,1,EA,Required Supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,$50 PER TERM MAX UNLESS APPROVED BY VRC,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Required Supplies         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,3,0,1,EA,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Handling Charges * Applicable only to books & supplies         
8257,344249022,5745,GUILLERMO,08/29/2022,4,0,1,EA,Mandatory Taxes,08/22/2022,08/22/2023,,38424677,ABC~~~EFG@YAHOO.COM,29001332,Mandatory Taxes
```

Comment: I tried your code with some production files and they all worked. Really appreciate your help. I specially like the way you put all the comments in your code, so it is very useful for me to understand and learn from it. You are a great mentor. I have upvoted your answer already.